# VPN in OSX is ignoring the subnet mask from DHCP

Tags: macos, network, vpn

We've set up a VPN in our office, and are having problems connecting the native VPN client in OSX.

Our DHCP subnet mask is 255.128.0.0, but when we check the connection in ifconfig it reports as 255.255.255.0 and we can't ping most of the network to which we are connecting.

About the only thing that searching on the internet came up with is a 3 year old thread on the apple support forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2642144?threadID=2642144

We have no problems with any other VPN clients (Windows and Linux).

Update:

- 1 Mac running OSX 10.8.3 is getting a subnet of 255.255.255.0
- 1 Mac running OSX 10.8.3 is getting a subnet of 255.0.0.0
- Mac running OSX 10.6.8 is getting a subnet of 255.0.0.0

Of course, none of these are correct, but at least the second two devices can access the whole range of our network (even if they go beyond it).

Update 2:

After working with other Mac users out of the office - it appears that this is an ISP thing, as it only happens with this one user, and they are the only person out of 6 tests now that are having this problem (of course, they don't have a Windows machine to try that out on the same connection).

Since this is looking like it isn't the Mac configuration, can it be moved to serverfault or somewhere better suited to networking questions?

Comment: Let's [chat] whether to migrate this. It's squarely on topic as written and we could re-phrase the question and have you ask that over at SF by focusing on the router / VPN equipment involved. It's hard to guess where the problem is when we don't know the answer yet.

Comment: As to the question, Apple's native VPN settings have a lot of flexibility, so you might need to describe the problem in more detail (VPN server software and settings, what exactly you entered in the Mac side) although use care to not divulge the secret keys and making sure that if you change the IP addresses, you change parts to make an equivalent network setup).

Comment: I feel like this is more of a problem with the VPN server setup, not the clients... How is the left & right ip source and subnet set up on the server?